# Create a counter for .map that persists across component mount/unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that is being mounted/unmounted several times. Within the component, I need multiple .maps, that need to be numbered.

I cannot seem to get a counter that will persist across mount/unmount, so that the .map values will increment appropriately. I've been trying with React Hooks, but keep running to the issue of "too many re-renders"

My component is:

```
    const url = `http://mysite.test/jsonapi/paragraph/lo_ec_ac/${props.id}`
    const [data,loading] = useFetch(url);
    const Ac = data.data;
    const [state,setState] = useState({counter:0});

    return(
        <Fragment>
        {loading ? ("Loading...") : (
            <Fragment>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="2">LO{props.LoNum} {Ac.attributes.field_lo}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {Ac.attributes.field_pass.map((pass,index)=>
                            <div>{setState({counter:state.counter+1})}{state.counter}{Ac.attributes.field_pass}</div>
                        )}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {Ac.attributes.field_merit}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {Ac.attributes.field_dist}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </Fragment>
        )}
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default UnitAc
```

I'd be extremely grateful for any pointers on how to make this work.

Comment: You're getting the `too many re-renders` rerenders error because you can't set state in render, as it will trigger a rerender every render, creating an infinite loop. If I understand correctly, do you just want each field to have an index starting from 1? And should these indices stay the same or increase from the last each render?

Comment: You can't use `setState` while returning render markup. What is it that you exactly want? Number each `Ac.attributes.field_pass` value?

Comment: You can just use `index+1` if all you want to render are increasing numbers starting from 1.

Comment: This component gets mounted multiple times, so the map of Ac.attributes.field_pass gets reset to 1 each time the component is mounts. I'd like these values to continue to increment, rather than reset on component mounting.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy - that is exactly what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: If your component unmounts  and mounts again, your data too will be fetched again. In such a case why would you need your counter to reset

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - The number of the .map values is not coming from the data. The numbering needs to be generated by the code, as it builds a table. What I need is a persistent counter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the `index` of each item from `map`, you don't need any counter state, and by removing it it'll fix your state management errors as well.

```
    const url = `http://mysite.test/jsonapi/paragraph/lo_ec_ac/${props.id}`
    const [data,loading] = useFetch(url);
    const Ac = data.data;

    return(
        <Fragment>
        {loading ? ("Loading...") : (
            <Fragment>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan="2">LO{props.LoNum} {Ac.attributes.field_lo}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {Ac.attributes.field_pass.map((pass,index)=>
                            <div>{index + 1}{Ac.attributes.field_pass}</div>
                        )}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {Ac.attributes.field_merit}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {Ac.attributes.field_dist}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </Fragment>
        )}
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default UnitAc
```